# Hiding some columns based on who is viewing the data, SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, credentials

I have a SSRS report that contains both cost and price of products.
What I want to do is based on who is viewing the report hide or show costs. price will always display.
I spent some time online, but I got lost. I am new to this topic and don't know where to start.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What I found so far is to leave the data source and database alone and show or hide columns based on user on the report side.                                   By applying either one of these two solutions:

Comment: 1- Creating two tablix in the report. one of them has both price and cost column and second one just have the price. Then on the tablix visibility for the first one I set:

Comment: IIf(User!UserID in (Accounting group), false, true)

Comment: and for the visibility of second tablix, i will set:

Comment: IIf(User!UserID in (Accounting group), true, false)

Comment: 2- another option would be hiding the content of cost column for non accounting user group.

Comment: How else I can accomplish this to be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways:

1. Have 2 (or more) versions of this report --- one has the column hidden, the other one has it visible. Then put these 2 reports in different folder on SSRS server, set different access to the folders for your target audience groups accordingly. My company is using this way to solve the problem.
2. Create a hidden parameter to read the user's ID (by setting the default value to be User!UserID). Then set the visibility of the column to be based on the value of this parameter. That's my basic idea. (To implement, you may need another Boolean parameter and several datasets of your user group) But the drawback of this solution is that hiding a column is not like hiding a group --- it may look very weird sometimes, not the way you want them to be at all.

Comment: Thank you William for your answer. I got your second way completely. It looks the same as what I myself found and put in the comment below the question. While trying that I noticed that hiding a column can be impossible if it is part of a row group (Which in my case is). Therefore I either have to hide the content of a column or having two tablixes in my report and hide or show based on the user viewing the report.

Comment: However this question still remains for me: Is there any better solution? How about all those credential settings I can see on report manager and ssrs data source? How can I use them and show or not show costing data to report viewer?

Comment: I'm not very sure about the report manager and data source, but I don't think it would work either.